# Why do we say intersection of finite subcollection of elements in topology definition?

Tags: general-topology

According to definition of a topology on a set $X$ (pg-76, *Munkres*):

[image: 1]

Why is the phrase "*any finite subcollection*" so important in case of intersection; unlike union, where *any subcollection (finite or countable)* is sufficient? What would go wrong if we write "*any subcollection (finite or countable)*" instead of "*any finite subcollection*" in the third property?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, The property 2 means that the union of the elements of any subcollection is in $\mathcal{T}$. You can choose any subcollection, with any cardinal, in some case it could even be $2^{2^{2^{2^{\aleph_0}}}}$. The property 3 means that the intersection must be finite, that is, of cardinal $<\aleph_0$

Comment: To add to John Ma's answer.. if you allowed infinite intersections, you could - in many cases - end up with the discrete topology which is pretty awful given how boring it is.

Comment: Yetter's answer here seems to be right: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_does_one_take_arbitrary_union_and_finite_intersection_when_defining_the_topology_of_a_set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take $\mathbb R$ as an example. In $\mathbb R$, you could have

$$\{a\}  = \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N} (a-\frac 1n, a+\frac 1n).$$

Thus a countable intersection of open sets might not be open (at least in $\mathbb R)$. 
Indeed, if you use this together $(2)$, all sets in $\mathbb R$ will be open!

On the other hand, note that open sets in $\mathbb R$ is defined by: $U$ is open if for all $x\in U$, there is $\epsilon >0$ so that $(x-\epsilon , x+\epsilon) \subset U$. From the definition $(2)$ and $(3)$ are automatically satisfied.